# Using print() (the function version) in Python2.x

Tags: python, printing, python-2.x, function-call

I understand the difference between a statement and an expression, and I understand that Python3 turned print() into a function.

However I ran a print() statement surrounded with parenthesis on various Python2.x interpreters and it ran flawlessly, I didn't even have to import any module.

My question: Is the following code `print("Hello SO!")` evaluated as a statement or an expression in Python2.x?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Consider the following expressions:

```
a = ("Hello SO!")
a = "Hello SO!"
```

They're equivalent.  In the same way, with a statement:

```
statement_keyword("foo")
statement_keyword "foo"
```

are also equivalent.

Notice that if you change your print function to:

```
print("Hello","SO!")
```

You'll notice a difference between python 2 and python 3.  With python 2, the `(...,...)` is interpteted as a tuple since print is a statement whereas in python 3, it's a function call with multiple arguments.

Therefore, to answer the question at hand, `print` is evaluated as a statement in python 2.x unless you `from __future__ import print_function` (introduced in python 2.6)

Comment: Would using from __future__ import print_function hurt in Python3? It doesn't give an import error.

Comment: @sgoblin -- Nope.  the `__future__` module gurantees that nothing will ever be removed from it.  It's effectively a no-op on python3.x

Answer (score 22):

`print("Hello SO!")` is evaluated as the statement `print ("Hello SO!")`, where the argument to the `print` statement is the expression `("Hello SO!")`.

This can make a difference if you are printing more than one value; for example `print("Hello", "world")` will print the 2-element tuple `('Hello', 'world')` instead of the two strings `"Hello"` and `"world"`.

For compatibility with Python 3 use `from __future__ import print_function`:

```
>>> print("Hello", "world")
('Hello', 'world')
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("Hello", "world")
Hello world
```

Comment: If you want to be compatible with python2.5 and python3.x you can use string interpolation (although I don't think too many people are advocating that these days ...)

Comment: This is also quite interesting.  Note that if you put this into a script, it will fail because `__future__` imports must occur at the beginning of the file, but by some deep python magic, it works in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

It is still evaluated as a statement, you are simply printing `("Hello SO!")`, which simply evaluates to `"Hello SO!"` since it is not a tuple (as mentioned by delnan).

Comment: And to be clear, `("Hello SO!")` is exactly equivalent to `"Hello SO!"` -- it's not a tuple.

Comment: Thanks @delnan, I saw your comment right before posting a nice answer about 1-element tuples.

Comment: And to expand on delnan's comment, to create a 1-tuple, you need a comma (e.g. `("Hello SO!",)`)