# Python: Invalid Syntax on line 1 (file <string>)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming in general and I wrote this code on Sublime Text, and I can't see the error in it.

```
print("Please enter a quote you would like to use: ")
quote = str(input())
print(quote.upper())
print()
print(quote.lower())
print()
print(quote.capitalise())
print()
print(quote.title())
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please give the version of your python or the whole traceback of the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `input()` with `raw_input()`:

```
print("Please enter a quote you would like to use: ")
quote = str(raw_input())
```

Or even:

```
quote = raw_input("Please enter a quote you would like to use: ")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code in your answer does not work in the general case: either `print()` is a function and `raw_input()` does not exist (Python 3), or `print` is a statement (Python 2).

Comment: If you issue `from __future__ import print_function` or you pass it a single argument, yes (so I updated my previous comment because it does indeed work in that case). If you pass more than one argument, Python 2 will interpret them as a tuple, which is usually not what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12162629/464709.

Comment: I know that, thanks. But in this case it will still work as expected.

Comment: Thanks mishik, I used 'raw_input' and it worked..why is this?

Comment: In python 2 raw_input() just returns you a string, while input() tries to execute the input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason isn't about whether to use `raw_input()` or `input()`. It's about taking an input in the first place. Sublime Text does not allow a user to give an input. Refer to here: [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input).

You can try [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Comment: I think OP means that Sublime does not show any syntax errors, not that it's a plugin for Sublime or something.

Comment: I have written other codes which have worked, however any code involving the user entering a string come up with a syntax error on line 1..so should I replace Sublime?

Comment: @user2575745 Yes, every time you use something to take an input (eg `input()` or `raw_input()`, an error will be raised because Sublime Text does not allow the user to give an input. Perhaps use another IDE, if you plan on doing this, yes