# python all combinations of two files lines

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

If I have two files:

#### file car.txt

```
ford, Chrysler, pontiac, cadillac
```

#### file color.txt

```
red, green, white, yellow
```

What is the pythonic way to make all possible combination of color and car?

*example output*

```
ford red
ford green
ford white
ford yellow
Chrysler red
Chrysler green
and so on...
```

Comment: [`from product from itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or simple nested for loops.

Comment: what have you tried and what is not working?  You're asking for the most pythonic way but it would help to see what you've tried.

Comment: Does it have to be car then color or can it be both color then car and car then color? If order doesn't matter you can just leverage itertools.permutations

Comment: I try nested for loops but the first for loop stop it at the first line

Comment: show us the code that did not work.

Comment: for car in carfile:
    for color in colorfile:
        print color.rstrip(), car

ford red
ford green
ford white
ford yellow
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I understand you're quite new here, it would be best to put this in the body of the question as some sample output.  You can preface lines with 4 spaces to give them a "code" like output.

Comment: @marioLetterman: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use two for loop like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function  
# remove the above line if you're using Python 3.x

with open('color.txt') as f:
    colors = ', '.join(f.read().splitlines()).split(', ')

with open('car.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        for car in i.strip().split(', '):
            for color in colors:
                print(car, color)
```

Comment: `[(i, j) for i in cars for j in colors]` I prefer this as it is both expressive as to what it does and terse in how it is presented.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Why build a list?

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: I don't think that a list comprehension would be clear than two `for` loop. Also we really don't need a list in this case.

Comment: nowhere in the requirements does this user ask to print this output, and it is far more likely in practice to need to join lists and use them later and store them somewhere.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: Okay I don't care about that. However, let me edit my answer.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon OP gives example output.

Comment: Providing output != a requirement to print.  Simply "this is the desired results." Please understand my initial edit changed it from "e.g." to "sample output" nowhere did it ask how to print it.  Though that doesn't preclude this person from needing it, it was simply not included as a requirement.

Comment: I forgot... those file can have 4 as well as 400 lines

Comment: @marioLetterman: No problem, but what's the output format do you want? Print it out? Put it in a list? Or write into another file?

Comment: @Kevin Guan: Just print out is fine, no matter the order

Comment: @Kevin Guan: your code output is ("ford\nChrysler\npontiac\ncadillac", "red\ngreen\nwhite\nyellow").

Comment: @marioLetterman: Oh, that because you're using Python 2.x. Let me edit that.

Comment: @marioLetterman: I done, just use `from __future__ import print_function` before run the code. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162629/using-print-in-python2-x) for more details.

Comment: @ Kevin Guan: That's exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @marioLetterman: If it works, remember accept it. Please check our [tour] and [help] about that :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
import itertools

a = ['ford', 'Chrysler', 'pontiac', 'cadillac']
b = ['red', 'green', 'white', 'yellow']

for r in itertools.product(a, b):
    print (r[0] + " " + r[1])

print (list(itertools.product(a,b))) #If you would like the lists for later modification.
```

Comment: what if the files have much more of 4 line?

Comment: @marioLetterman You must figure out how you will cipher thought and assemble lists a and b. This code will work with any two lists of any lengths. Add 'acura' to list a and 'black' to list b and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, but how do i fill the list if i have 400 items? Can I import from file?

Comment: @marioLetterman You should open a question for that and show the file so I can understand how we would process it.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic would mean using the tools available.

Use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the comma separated line:

```
with open('cars.txt') as cars_file:
    cars = next(csv.reader(cars_file))

with open('colors.txt') as colors_file:
    colors = next(csv.reader(colors_file))
```

Use [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create the [Cartesian product](https://www.google.dk/search?q=cartesian+product):

```
from itertools import product
```

In Python 3.x:

```
for car, color in product(cars, colors):
    print(car, color)
```

In Python 2.7:

```
for car, color in product(cars, colors):
    print car, color
```

In one line:

```
print('\n'.join('{car} {color}'
                .format(car=car, color=color)
                for car, color in product(cars, colors)))
```

Comment: your output code "('ford', 'red')" for first one, "ford red" second one.