# What are the difference between sep and end in print function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
pets = ['boa', 'cat', 'dog']
for pet in pets:
    print(pet)

boa
cat
dog
>>> for pet in pets:
        print(pet, end=', ')

boa, cat, dog, 
>>> for pet in pets:
        print(pet, end='!!! ')

boa!!! cat!!! dog!!!
```

but what about sep? i tried to replace end by sep but nothing happened but i know that sep is used to separete while printing, how and when can i use sep? what are the differences between sep and end?

Comment: `sep` is used to separate arguments passed as `*args`. Try running `print('a', 'b', 'c', sep=', ')`

Comment: yea i got it, thanks, its all that sep wasn't working because i placed it in a for loop... only end works in for loop..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) uses `sep` to separate the arguments, and `end` after the last argument. Your example was confusing because you only gave it one argument. This example might be clearer:

```
>>> print('boa', 'cat', 'dog', sep=', ', end='!!!\n')
boa, cat, dog!!!
```

Of course, `sep` and `end` only work in Python 3's print function. For Python 2, the following is equivalent.

```
>>> print ', '.join(['boa', 'cat', 'dog']) + '!!!'
boa, cat, dog!!!
```

You can also use a backported version of the print function in Python 2:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('boa', 'cat', 'dog', sep=', ', end='!!!\n')
boa, cat, dog!!!
```

Comment: It's possible to use `print` function in Python 2 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12162629/2301450

Comment: Python 2 has a [print statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt), @vaultah, that has important differences. For one thing, it doesn't support `sep` and `end`.

Comment: I'm just saying that your claim that it only works in Python 3 is incorrect.

Comment: My claim was that only `sep` and `end` work in Python 3, @vaultah. I've clarified the answer.

Comment: Actually, Python 2's print function [supports `sep` and `end`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: Oh right, @vaultah, I forgot about the `__future__` module. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following two are equivalent:

```
print(*array, sep='abc')
print('abc'.join(str(x) for x in array))
```

Answer (score 0):

sep='' and end='' are two different thing. ignore space and make variable as a single string.. like: `a b`-->ab
But `end=''` make `a b` -->a b 
see the below example.
for sep=' '

```
from itertools import permutations
s,k = input().split()
for i in list(permutations(sorted(s), int(k))):
    print(*i,sep='')

    ''' output for sep='': 
    HACK 2
    AC
    AH
    AK
    CA
    CH
    CK
    HA
    HC
    HK
    KA
    KC
    KH
    '''
```

for end=' '

```
    from itertools import permutations

    s, k = input().split()
    for i in list(permutations(sorted(s), int(k))):
        print(*i, end='')
    '''
HACK 2
A CA HA KC AC HC KH AH CH KK AK CK H
Process finished with exit code 0
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

In array variable instead of sep you can use join

```
pets = ['boa', 'cat', 'dog']
res=",".join(pets)
print(res)
```

Output

```
boa,cat,dog
```