# Why does the print function leave a space at the end?

Tags: python, printing, space

Why does it remain a space between Ste and !? How can I eliminate it, without using a difficult function?

```py
a = input("Enter a name: ")

Enter a name: Ale

print("Hello,", a, "!")

Hello, Ste !
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the difference between sep and end in print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513028/what-are-the-difference-between-sep-and-end-in-print-function)

Comment: You should learn more about the print function: [check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513028/what-are-the-difference-between-sep-and-end-in-print-function)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `print` separates each of its arguments with a space. You can change it by specifying the `sep` parameter with something else, including an empty string. This should work:

```
print("Hello, ", a, "!", sep="")
=> Hello, Ale!
```

Answer (score 1):

Comma `,` by default leaves a space after a string. You can try using `+`:

`print("Hello, " + a + "!") 
 =>Hello, Ste!`

Answer (score 0):

Use the strip function to cut the space at the initial and end of the string.

```
print("Hello,", a.strip(), "!", sep="")
```