# Want to remove the space between Last name and ","

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(row["first"], row["last"], ",", "born", row["birth"])
```

Output:

```
Ronald Bilius Weasley , born 1980
```

I want to remove space after Weasley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sep` option like this.  `sep` is used to denote how you want to separate. By default, python uses space for comma. you can change that by resetting the value of sep to ''

```
print(row["first"], " ",row["last"], ", born ", row["birth"], sep = '')
```

Output:

```
Ronald Bilius Weasley, born 1980
```

There are many ways to solve your code. The above one is one of the ways. Here is a link to look at a few options.

[What are the difference between sep and end in print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513028/what-are-the-difference-between-sep-and-end-in-print-function)

You can try to use `str.join()` or `.format()` options or simple `+` to concatenate strings.

To learn more about format printing, see this link. https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

The , in print will automatically show you a whitespace after it, so you can prevent this like this:

```
print(row["first"], row["last"] + ",", "born", row["birth"])
```

Alternatively you could also do this:

```
print("{} {}, born {}".format(row["first"], row["last"], row["birth"]))
```